# NodeJS "readline" module not outputting prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, readline

Using NodeJS, I was trying to make a 'note' manager just for fun, but when I tried to use readline.question() to get the user's input on what they would like to do(i.e create a new note, delete a note), the prompt wouldn't be displayed. Any suggestions on how I could fix this issue?

[Link To Project](https://repl.it/@TheCoiledViper/File-Management-Node)

`

```
    fileDatabase = [];
    var reply;
    var FileName;
    var FileContent;

    var readline = require('readline');
    var async = require('async');

    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });

    class NewFile {
        constructor(fileName,fileContent){
            this.fileName = fileName
            this.fileContent = fileContent
        }
    };

    console.log("Hello! Welcome to your file management system.")

    async.whilst(

        function(){
            return reply != "5";
        },

        function(callback){ 
            rl.question("Press a number:\n1: Create a new file.\n2: View a file.\n3: Add to a file.\n4: Delete a file.\n5: Exit this program.", function(answer) {
                var reply = answer
                console.log(reply)
                rl.close();
            });

            if (reply === "1") {
                rl.question("What would you like to name this file?", function(answer){
                    var FileName = answer
                    rl.close()
                });
                rl.question("Write onto your file. You will be able to edit it later.", function(answer){
                    var FileContent = answer
                    rl.close()
                });         
            }
            setTimeout(callback, 1000);
        },

        function(err) {
             console.err("we encountered an error", err); 
        }
    )
```

`

Comment: Are you able to get the list of

`Press a number:
1: Create a new file.
2: View a file.
3: Add to a file.
4: Delete a file.
5: Exit this program.`

Comment: @HardikShah  When I run the program, the list isn't outputted to the console, if that's what you mean.

Comment: In my case the list comes perfect but after selecting 1 as choice, nothing happened. Can you please add NodeJS async and readline module version?

Comment: @HardikShah on my online ide (repl.it), the async module is version 2.6.1, however I don't think the read line module is actually supported which explains why I the list of options wasn't outputting

Comment: Yes `readline` module is not supported to repl.it online IDE. Can you please try to your local environment? What was your local environment behavior?

Comment: @HardikShah At the moment I don't have a local environment, so I'm only programming on online IDEs

Comment: Take a look at the answer. Your prompt issue is resolved. Hav a fun ahead ;) :)

Comment: @HardikShah Thanks!

Comment: If you found answer appropriate and solved your issue then mark answer accepted and do vot too... ;) :)

Comment: Ok sure :) Im  really new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are only using an online editor. (At least I am trying to solve your problem of prompting issue.)

I would suggest https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground

Copy your code into `app.js` file.

You will have the `Terminal` tab. Please install dependencies first.

> npm install -g asynch
>
> npm install -g readline

By which, you will have `node_modules` folder under the tree.

And click on `node app.js` link left side highlighted by black color.

**Couple of things you should take care about your code:**

1. Please try to assign some default value of `reply` maybe you can do as `var reply = 0`
2. Wrap the list code to the condition if `reply = 0`.
3. `if (reply === "1")` this condition will strictly check with string. use instead `if(reply == 1)`.
4. And modify your code as per your requirement to fall into next question.

**Below is modified code:**

```
fileDatabase = [];
var reply = 0;
var FileName;
var FileContent;

var readline = require('readline');
var async = require('async');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

class NewFile {
    constructor(fileName, fileContent) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileContent = fileContent;
    }
}

console.log('Hello! Welcome to your file management system.');

async.whilst(
    function() {
        return reply != '5';
    },

    function(callback) {
 
        if (reply === 0) {
            rl.question(
                'Press a number:\n1: Create a new file.\n2: View a file.\n3: Add to a file.\n4: Delete a file.\n5: Exit this program.\n',
                function(answer) {
                     reply = answer;
                    rl.close();
                }
            );
      }

    if (reply == 1) {
        rl.question('What would you like to name this file?\n', function(answer) {
            var FileName = answer;
            rl.close();
        });
        rl.question(
            'Write onto your file. You will be able to edit it later.\n',
            function(answer) {
                var FileContent = answer;
                rl.close();
            }
        );
    }
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
},

    function(err) {
        console.err('we encountered an error', err);
    }
);
```

**For your reference:**

[image]